# set background colors for text and listview, listview does not change the color with setbackground

Tags: android-layout

I have a view with listview and text view. I want to set diff colors for textview  and     listview. also list view also few items which does not fill entire screen.

need help to fix the issue

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_weight="0.12" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/songsbyyear" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="22dp"
    android:background="@color/steelblue" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:background="@color/darkslateblue"  android:layout_height="456dp">    </ListView>
```

First screen xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_weight="0.12" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/songsbyyear" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="22dp"
    android:background="@color/steelblue" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:divider="#FFCC00"    android:dividerHeight="4px"
    android:background="@color/darkslateblue" android:layout_height="456dp">  </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide drawable or Hex code for color to be the background. As you are getting this

```
Unable to resolve drawable "@color/steelblue" in attribute "background"
Unable to resolve drawable "@color/darkslateblue" in attribute "background"
```

So, provide an image and you can also use values like this "#FF00FF" etc

**EDIT:**

I have included a file my_color.xml in my values folder i.e. **res/values/my_color.xml**.

And my_color.xml inludes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
  <color name="steelblue">#4863A0</color>
  <color name="darkslateblue">#2B3856</color>
</resources>
```

It's working for me. Try this now.

Comment: i did define the hex codes in colors.xml,  <color name="darkslateblue">#2B3856</color>
  <color name="steelblue">#4863A0</color>

Comment: the colors were already defined in cololrs.xml, the issue is still there.

Comment: Still it does n't work, If i write a program with this screen only, it is working, I have a scenario, first screen it display the list, then based on selection i am launching another activity with the screen i mentioned above. some how the same colors works on first screen not on the second screen.

Comment: adding the first screen xml, i could see the first screen with colors, i am not sure why it is creating an issue after launching the second screen with the same colors.

Comment: May be there is some issue with your code. I don't have it so can't tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: yes, there is an issue with my code, the code also has setbackground for list. I removed it. it helped thanks.

Comment: If it helped then please accept or vote for my answer. Thanks =))